# Recursion using main() function

Tags: c, linux, recursion, segmentation-fault

I am writing a program to calculate factorial using recursion of `main`() function.

```
/* Print factorial */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char **p;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int n, rv;
        if (argc < 2) {
                printf("Usage: a.out <value>\n");
                exit(-1);
        }
        n = atoi(argv[1]);
        if (!n) {
                rv = 0;
        } else {
                if (n == 1) {
                        rv = 1;
                } else {
                        n = n - 1;
                        **p = n;
                        main(2, p);
                }
        }
        printf("%d\n", rv);
        return 0;
}
```

The program compiles using `gcc` but on execution, I am getting a Segmentation Fault at `**p = n`. Can somebody help me to modify the above program to get the correct result. Also, what is the logic to capture correct `rv` value between successive recursive calls in `main`()?

Comment: Why would you explicitly use something that you know is bad?

Comment: How to remove the seg-fault first?

Comment: @icepack: FUBAR - Fully Upvoted Because of Arbitrary Recursion

Comment: `p` is unassigned, can't deference it. Do it correctly: try to write 'standard' code with good practices

Comment: You should compile with all warnings and debugging info, that is with `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux, improve your code till no warnings are given, and learn to use the `gdb` debugger (and also `valgrind`)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you don't seem to care about standard and stuffs, here is an implementation of the recursive main function for printing factorial, that compiles on gcc (I only test on Windows). Since it doesn't follow standard, there is no guarantee that it will compiles on other compiler/platform.

Writing such code for fun is OK, but never let the bad behavior follows into serious coding project or workplace.

```
/* Print factorial */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char buf[16];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int n, rv;

        if (argc < 2) {
                printf("Usage: a.out <value>\n");
                exit(-1);
        }

        n = atoi(argv[1]);
        if (!n) {
                rv = 1;
        } else {
                if (n == 1) {
                    rv = 1;
                } else {
                    char *pt = buf;
                    char **pt2 = &pt - 1;

                    sprintf(buf, "%d", n - 1);
                    rv = main(2, pt2) * n;
                }
        }
        printf("%d\n", rv);

        return rv;
}
```

Comment: YeeeHoooo... yes this solved my problem !

Comment: How can you claim "here is a working implementation"? - at best it happens to work on some set of tested platforms, as far as you could tell.

Comment: @TonyD: Agree, edited. It is bad code anyway.

Comment: Well -1 to +1 for the more appropriately cautioned example - hackers, live long and crash...!

Answer (score -3):

Only operating system can call `main` when it runs the program. Other than operating system no one can call any function named `main`. So if want to calculate factorial using recursion then you have to write another function to calculate that recursively and call that function from `main`.

You can ask why is this? Answer is this is the syntax.